# Transpose columns to rows and replace values by binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table :

```
Team Department1 Department2 Department3
1    Marketing   Sales       Finance
2    Sales       IT          HR
```

I want to transpose data like below :

```
Team Marketing Sales  Finance IT HR
1    1         1      1       0  0
2    0         1      0       1  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` logic:

```
select team,
       (case when 'Marketing' in (Department1, Department2, Department3) then 1 else 0
        end) as marketing,
       (case when 'Sales' in (Department1, Department2, Department3) then 1 else 0
        end) as sales,
       (case when 'Finance' in (Department1, Department2, Department3) then 1 else 0
        end) as finance,
       (case when 'IT' in (Department1, Department2, Department3) then 1 else 0
        end) as it,
       (case when 'HR' in (Department1, Department2, Department3) then 1 else 0
        end) as hr
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Team,
       (CASE WHEN 'Marketing' IN (Department1, Department2, Department3) THEN 1 else 0
        end) AS Marketing
...
FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Unpivot your table first**, then it's pretty simple conditional aggregation.

```sql
select team,
       count(case when v.Department = 'Marketing' then 1 end) as marketing,
       count(case when v.Department = 'Sales' then 1 end) as sales,
       count(case when v.Department = 'Finance' then 1 end) as finance,
       count(case when v.Department = 'IT' then 1 end) as it,
       count(case when v.Department = 'HR' then 1 end) as hr
from t
cross apply (
    (Department1),
    (Department2),
    (Department3)
) v(Department)
group by team;
```

**You table design is faulty. You should have `TeamDepartment` as a separate many-to-many linking table**